# How to turn off WAL in hbase 2.0.0 with java API?

Tags: java, hbase, wal

I wonder if there is any way to disable WAL (write ahead log) operations when inserting new data to a hbase table with JAVA API?

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Mutation.html#setDurability(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Durability)

Comment: @shay__: I am usin hbase 2.0.0. Do you know some examples on how to use the class Mutation?

Comment: Please post your code without skipping WAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HBase 2.0.0

To skip WAL at an individual update level (for a single Put or Delete):

```
Put p = new Put(ROW_ID).addColumn(FAMILY, NAME, VALUE).setDurability(Durability.SKIP_WAL)
```

To set this setting for the entire table (so you don't have to do it each time for each update):

```
TableDescriptorBuilder tBuilder = TableDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_ID));
tBuilder.setDurability(Durability.SKIP_WAL);
... continue building the table
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can we do the same from shell, without using Java API?